# UITableView jumps to top on appending new cells to it. How to prevent it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

At first I load 10 cells. Then on the bottom I load +10 more cells and reload tableView. But in this case my tableView jumps to top. Can I prevent it?

I've tried the next solution:

```
let scrollOffsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
self.tableView.contentOffset.y = scrollOffsetY
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

but it did not help me at all. Is there another solution?

Comment: Are you getting all data from api?

Comment: Get count of that array and divide it by 10 and in willDisplayCell method get last row. Tell me if you want more help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reloading the entire table view, try `tableView:insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` instead inside `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates`. This'll intelligently load the `UITableView` without scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

don't set the contentOffSet

Comment: to use both of them in this order?

Comment: Just try as @Varun said insert new rows in between the begin and end updates